# Get position of a div in the hierarchy

Tags: javascript, dom, html, traversal

I'm working with JavaScript, and I need to find the position of a div given the entire DOM tree. When given the same tree, I need to end up knowing a traversal starting at the root that will get us to the div we're looking at. Please feel free at ask follow up questions.

Cheers.

Comment: you really need to traverse the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you onto the right track. I'm not 100% certain of the browser coverage of `getAttribute`, so test this on targeted browsers if needed.

```
getNodeAndParent = function(o) {
    var nodeTarget,strParents,strNodeName,strNodeId,strNodeClass,strReturnValue;
    if (o.constructor === String) {
        nodeTarget = document.getElementById(o);
        if (nodeTarget === undefined) {
            throw "You must specify a valid node ID";
        }
    }
    else {
        nodeTarget = o;
    }
    strNodeName = nodeTarget.nodeName
    strNodeId = nodeTarget.getAttribute('id');
    strNodeClass = nodeTarget.className;
    strReturnValue = strNodeName + (strNodeId ? '#' + strNodeId : '') + (strNodeClass ? '.' + strNodeClass : '');
    if (strNodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'html') {
        strReturnValue = getNodeAndParent(nodeTarget.parentNode) + ' > ' + strReturnValue;
    }

    return strReturnValue;
}

//Example:
getNodeAndParent('prettify-lang');
```

In the case of running this against this question page in Firebug, you get `"HTML > BODY.question-page > DIV.container > DIV#content > DIV#prettify-lang"`

Comment: This was one of the things I considered - ended up using xPath.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to return. 
Its simpler to start at the node and go toward the root,
rather than the reverse.

```
function descent(who, ret){
    var A= [];
    while(who.parentNode){      
        A[A.length]= ret? who: who.nodeName;
        who= who.parentNode;
    }
    return A.reverse();
}
```

/*

```
test

var what= document.getElementById('funblurb1') 

descent(what)>>
HTML,BODY,DIV,DIV

descent(what,1)>>
[object HTMLHtmlElement],[object HTMLBodyElement],

[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement]
```

*/